# Including tags in the with include tag

Tags: python, django

How can I insert this:

```
<strong>{% trans "Error!" %}</strong> {% trans "blablabla." %}
```

Instead of "xxx" here:

```
{% include "alert.html" with connotation="error" message="xxx" %}
```

Please advise.

Comment: what did you try to do it so far?

Comment: You can't. In order to achieve it you might modify the `alert.html` template to conditionally display the block you want to pass, e.g. `{%if message %}..block goes here..{%endif%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't do that unless you create the complete message in view and pass it as a template context parameter.

Instead of passing complete message i would suggest to pass some error code and based on that show the appropriate message in `"alert.html"`.

So your include statement will change to something like this:

```
{% include "alert.html" with connotation="error" error_code=err_code %}
```

and inside `alert.html`, you can put conditions to show appropriate message.

```
{% if error_code == "404" %}
  <strong>{% trans "Not Found!" %}</strong>
{% endif %}
```